# make two db calls and render the content of two different array populated by the results in one ejs page

Tags: javascript, database, express, ejs, render

I'm trying express and I have to render a page passing two arrays that is populated by two DB calls,
the query is correct, in fact, if I render only one array in the ejs page it passes the content.
When i pass a single array i do this :

```
dao.getAllSerie().then((show) => {
        res.render('index', {
            series: show,
        })
    }).catch(() => res.status(500).end());
```

If I do this everything goes well and nothing is wrong, content is rendered and ejs page is filled with value.
The demand is: "If I have to render two arrays that is filled with two results of two different call to the DB how can I do?"
I've tried this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    series = [];
    categories = [];

    //CALL TO A FUNCTION THAT SELECT FROM DB ASSIGN THE RESULT TO 'SERIES'
    dao.getAllSerie().then((show) => { series = show; })
        .catch(() => res.status(500).end());

    //CALL TO A FUNCTION THAT SELECT FROM DB ASSIGN THE RESULT TO 'CATEGORIES'
    dao.getCategorie().then((category) => { categories = category; })
        .catch(() => res.status(500).end());

    //IN THE RENDER PAGE EACH 'CATEGORIES' AND 'SERIES' ARE NULL
    res.render('index', {
        series: series,
        categories: categories
    })
})
```

But either series and categories results null which means that the ejs page is rendered without dynamics content.
I think is some sort of async problem, somebody know if it's possible and how?
Here the db call functions :

```
//GET OF ALL SERIES IN THE DB
exports.getAllSerie = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const sql = 'SELECT * FROM serie';
        db.all(sql, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(rows);
        });
    });
};

//GET OF ALL CATEGORIES IN THE DB
exports.getCategorie = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT categoria FROM serie';
        db.all(sql, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(rows);
        });
    });
};
```

I know that categories should be in a separated table but it's just to make some try.
Thank you in advance to all for the time.   Really grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store your 2 asynchronous functions in an array then use Promise.all to wait for all asynchronous calls to get back, THEN only render the page :

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  let dataFetchers = []

  dataFetchers.push(dao.getAllSerie) // the first async function
  dataFetchers.push(dao.getCategorie) // the second

  Promise.all(dataFetchers) // will wait for ALL promises to resolve or reject
    .then(dataArray => {
      let series = dataArray[0] // the first promise's result
      let categories = dataArray[1] // the second

      res.render('index', { // render only once you have ALL the datum
        series: series,
        categories: categories
      })
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(500).end())
})
```

Comment: eureka, it works, so i was render while promises aren't finished yet?

Comment: exactly, you "lauched" 2 promises then rendered without waiting for the result

Comment: ok, thank you, you have just improve the skill of a person, thank you, have a great day